# How Sort forward,backward and output to file using a doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am really at a loss as to how to get a doubly linked list to work. I previously used parallel arrays to sort a user name and age with a bubblesort. 
 The goal is to read the name and age from the user and store the values into nodes. Print the values sorted forward and backward and I think using strcmp would be easier for this program because the bubblesort was very difficult for me.
 I need suggestions based on the code I have so far. What is the best way to get this program to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//create structure of person that can hold a name and an age that can be used in a doubly linked list

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct person //structure of person
  {
         char name [41];
         int age;
         struct person *next;//doubly linked list
         struct person *prev;       
  };

  typedef struct person people;//using a new type of our structure

  people first;//declade first of type people
  first.age = 12;//puts 12 in the age portion of the variable first of the structure person which can hold someones age

  strcpy (first.name, "sue");
  people *p; //creates a pointer to a storage location
  p = &first; //that storage location now has the contents of the storage location of first.
  (*p).age = 13; //this is the same as p->age=13; or arrow. This dereferences the pointer. arrow for pointer, (*x) 
  //dereferencing through structure
  //make two pointers to manage a doubly linked list
  //make two pointers of type people named head and tail
  people *head,*tail;
  *head = NULL;
  *tail = NULL;
  //start with printing rout9ine
  printit(head);//shows nothing
  //linked list
  void printit(people *h);
  {
            people *t;
            t=h;
            while (t != NULL)
            {
                  //print the information here, he didnt give me code so i need to remember this on my own
                  t = t->next;//continues the list      goes through pointers to the first node then destroyes t by making it
                  //the next. You can also use the h. 
            }
  }

  //sending address, pass by reference

  buildit(&head,&tail);
  //head is a pointer of type people, want the pointer not the value
  //so you need a pointer of a pointer, it acccepts the address of head and tail which
  //is the address of the addres of the start and end of the linked list
  void buildit (people **h, people **t)
  {
           people *current;
           current = malloc (sizeof(people)); //creates space for a people structure, current points to it.
           //assume doubly linked list
           //t refers to the address of tail, if you want the contents of the address of tail you need *t.
           (*t) -> next = current;
           current -> prev = *t;
           *t = current;
  }

  //structure in iostream, called FILE
  FILE *out;
  out = fopen(/*name of the file*/ stringname, access); 
  //fopen opens a file, you can open stdin, com 1, com 2, opens keyboard or ports or files.
  //access has two values, r and w. r = read w = write. input reads from output writes to.
  out = fopen("output.txt","w"); //opens output.txt

  char filename [81];
  gets (filename); //allows a user to input the file they want to open. array of chars, reads entire string spaces and all
  out = fopen(filename,"w");

  if (out != NULL) //checks if file is open or note, if null no file opened up, it checks
  {
     fprintf (out, "formatstring"; parameterlist); //file print f        
     fscanf //adds file handle to parameters, thats it.
     fgets //same, file gets
  }
  //changing a file needs pass by reference, not value.
  ptintit(person*, FILE**);
  void printit(person*h, FILE**o)
  {
       fprintf (*o,",,,,,",...); 
  }


  system("PAUSE");    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you required to use a doubly-linked list? If not, using an array would be a much better option (as peterh suggested) since the elements would be placed in contiguous memory locations and each element access would be much more efficient, since a lot of unnecessary pointer dereferencing can be avoided.

Comment: Also, could you state the problem you're facing more clearly? Are you getting an incorrect output? Or do you want better performance?

Comment: No it has to be a doubly-linked list. I'm trying to wrap my head around the address of an address with pointers.

Comment: As I mentioned before, what is the exact problem you're facing? Are you getting an incorrect output? If so, please clearly highlight what you're inputs were and the output you got?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution, the [bubble sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) will do what you want.

In an environment where speed is important, the list would be converted to more suitable data structure for the task (f.e. to an array), and it would be sorted with a much faster algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

A list sort operation only requires a single linked list, so you could implement a sort using just the next pointers, then after the sort, making a pass through the list to set the previous pointers. Backwards versus forwards just needs to change the sense of the compare, unless you actually wanted to make a backwards sort that uses the previous pointers, then make a pass through the list to set the next pointers.

A bubble sort will work, but it would be easier to start off with a second empty list pointer (like node * sorted = NULL;), then remove nodes from the original list one at a time and insert them into the second list in the proper location. Another variation on this would be to scan the original list for the node with the largest value, then remove that node from the original list and prepend it to the sorted list.

A bottom up merge sort would be much faster, but probably not needed in this case.